# WPF interactivity trigger mousewheel not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this xaml attached to a grid (and I've tried it on a stackpanel):

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseWheel">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviousWeekCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I added the namespace:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

and referenced the interactivity dll in my solution. This is my first try with interactivity triggers so I'm not sure why it's not working -- that is, the mousewheel does nothing either way I scroll it.  I know the command works as it's the same command for a button that works properly. I get no errors and I'm not using any mvvm frameworks or anything. Did I miss a step?

Comment: Where do you use the trigers? In Button, where the binding does work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code does work. The reason why you have an issue should be, that `DataContext` of element, where you use the triggers has no `PreviousWeekCommand` command. You could use binding with `RelativeSource`

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.PreviousWeekCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ControlTypeWhereDataContextHasPreviousWeekCommand}}"/>
```

Comment: It does work -- I moved it to the usercontrol parent that already had the proper datacontext and it didn't seem to work, at first, but I had to find some sweet spots. I wonder if there is a way for all child elements to inherit those triggers